# Get the top-level domain of a page containing an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want to allow an iframe to request new data from the server (via ajax), only if the iframe is embedded in particular pages. **How can I get the top level domain within an iframe?**

At first I was thinking security would be easy, on my server I can simply check the `http_referrer` which is a standard thing sent with every HTTP request.

But then I realized this http_referrer is actually the domain of my iframe, not the domain that contains the iframe! So if I embedded my_iframe.com in my_site.com, the http_referrer is `my_iframe.com`, which doesn't help me know who is embedding the page.

So now I'm pursuing this alternative.

Comment: Answer was just to do `document.referrer` from the iframe. That gives the containing window regardless of whether it's the same origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `window.top` to access the top most window and the use the normal `location` object, however you will run into issues regarding the same origin policy if trying to access an external domain from within your iframe, i suggest you [check this community post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) about the `same-origin policy`.

```
window.top.location.href
window.top.location.host
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    alert(window.top.location.origin);
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e.message);
}
```